# no JavaScript alert appearing on submit

Tags: javascript

Trying to create a simple form with JavaScript validation to alert user when a text field is blank. When I open saved .html file in browser the form appears however when I click to submit no JavaScript alert is appearing, how do I make this JavaScript function work and have the alert appear on submit?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function validateForm() {

var errormessage= "";


    if (document.getElementsById('fullName').value ==""){errormessage += "First name must be filled out \n";
        }
    }

    if (document.getElementsById('fullName').value ==""){errormessage += "First name must be filled out \n";
        }
    }
    if (document.getElementsById('pNumber').value ==""){errormessage += "First name must be filled out \n";
        }
    }

    if (document.getElementsById('eMail').value ==""){errormessage += "First name must be filled out \n";
        }
    }

     if (document.getElementsById('aMessage').value ==""){errormessage += "First name must be filled out \n";
        }
    }   

    if (errormessage !="") {
        alert(errormessage);
        return false;
        }
    }


</script>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return validateForm ()">

<fieldset>
    <label>Your Name: 
    <input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullName"></label>
    <br>
    <label>Your Phone Number: 
    <input type="text" id="pNumber" name="pNumber"></label>
    <br>
    <label>Your Email Address: 
    <input type="text" id="eMail" name="eMail"></label>
    <br>
    <label>Message: 
    <input type="text" id="aMessage" name="aMessage"></label>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="click to submit">
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There's no functin `getElementsById`. It's singular `getElementById`. Didn't you see an error message in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems are there

**1** There should be `getElementById`.

**2** You are having double `}` after `if` statement. Put just one `}`.

This is what will work for you

```
function validateForm() {
    var errormessage= "";
    if (document.getElementById('fullName').value ==""){
        errormessage += "Name must be filled out \n";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('pNumber').value ==""){
        errormessage += "Phone Number must be filled out \n";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('eMail').value ==""){
        errormessage += "Email must be filled out \n";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('aMessage').value ==""){
        errormessage += "Message must be filled out \n";
    }   
    if (errormessage !="") {
        alert(errormessage);
        return false;
    }
}
```